# Рамки(border) у крайних и соседних элементов

Tags: jquery, css, border

Здравствуйте, подскажите способ сделать также?:
http://refills.bourbon.io/#er-toc-id-8 (второй пример) 
Там нет удвоения рамок между элементами и нет рамок у крайних элементов.
В CSS не нашел ничего похожего на :nth-child, да и при изменении ширины экрана порядок элементов меняется а эфект остается... это сделано за счет js?
Подскажите пожалуйста плагин или как реализовать на css (если не подключать refills).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

**Здесь нет JS**

Не туда смотрели, надо было поглядеть на эти классы:

```
.refills-patterns .grid-items .grid-item-big {
    width: 66.66667%;
}

.refills-patterns .grid-items .grid-item {
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

`.grid-item-big` - это большой блок, 2/3 ширины, `.grid-item` - маленький 1/3 ширины. Блоки укладываются за счет `display: inline-block`, так-что это только кажется, что это табличная верстка. Рамок (`border`) соответственно тоже нет, вместо них простой отступ между блоками - `margin`

При изменении размера экрана срабатывает [media-запрос](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)

```
.refills-patterns .grid-items .grid-item {
     width: 100%;/*обычное состояние*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 53.75em){
    .refills-patterns .grid-items .grid-item-big {
       width: 66.66667%;/*если широкий экран*/
    }

    .refills-patterns .grid-items .grid-item {
       width: 33.33333%;/*если широкий экран*/
    }
}
```

И ширина блоков становится 100%, если ширина экрана меньше обозначенной величины

Comment: я тож так подумал, но margin для .grid-item не нашел. А вот border справа и снизу есть у всех .grid-item, но отображается только у внутренних элементов..

Comment: @SilaevD , Действительно, `border`, а не `margin` иначе `width` вместе с отступом  `margin` давало бы в сумме больше чем 100%